# Linq result to double(Multidimensional-arrays) array?

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array

I want to assign linq result to double array. I have two object array. I fetch them like below:

```
var chartSeries = MeterReadings.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                  .Select(g => new
                  {
                     Name = g.Key,
                     Data = g.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray(),
                     Date = g.Select(x => x.ReadDate).ToArray()
                  }).ToArray();
```

And trying to assign code:

```
foreach (var item in chartSeries)
{
    int length = item.Data.Length;
    object[,] data =  ???  //first array item.Data and second item.Dates
    Series localSeries = new Series 
                         {
                              Name = item.Name, Data = new Data(data), Type = ChartType 
                         };
     Series.Add(localSeries);
 }
```

this line `object[,] data =  ???`  What should I write? I want something like `object[,] data =  { item.Data, item.Dates }`

I'm trying to get like this:

```
Data = new Data(new object[,]
       {
          { new DateTime(1970, 9, 27), 0 },
          { new DateTime(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 },
          { new DateTime(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 },
          { new DateTime(1970, 11, 2), 0.8 },
          { new DateTime(1970, 11, 9), 0.6 },
          { new DateTime(1970, 11, 16), 0.6 },
          { new DateTime(1970, 11, 28), 0.67 },
          { new DateTime(1971, 1, 1), 0.81 },
          { new DateTime(1971, 1, 8), 0.78 },
          { new DateTime(1971, 1, 12), 0.98 },
          { new DateTime(1971, 1, 27), 1.84 },
          { new DateTime(1971, 2, 10), 1.80 },
          { new DateTime(1971, 2, 18), 1.80 },                                                            
          { new DateTime(1971, 6, 12), 0 }
       })
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer use var :

```
var data = new object[2][];
data[0] = item.Data.Cast<Object>().ToArray();
data[1] = item.Date.Cast<Object>().ToArray();
```

With the precision you gave, you might use :

```
var data = item.Date.Zip(item.Data, (n, m) => new[] { n as object, m as object }).ToArray();
```

Comment: I agree this is more elegant, but it produces a jagged array, not a multidimensional array which was asked in the question. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you need:

```
object[,] data = new object[2,length];

for (int i; i < length; i++)
{
    data[0, i] = item.Date[i];
    data[1, i] = item.Data[i];
}
```

You will need to verify how the array should be constructed (`object[2,length]` or `object[length,2]`. Also, I'm assuming the dates should be put in 'first'.